# Number of Holes punched through a Plate of SAE 1010 Steel

Tags: steel, stresses

Reviewing for a National Board Exam:

> How many 5/16 inch holes can be punched in one motion in a steel plate
>   made of SAE 1010 Steel 7/16 inch thick using a force of 55 tons. The
>   ultimate strength for shear is 50 ksi and use 2 Factor of Safety

Answer is 5.

This is a common strength of materials question given among problem sets in engineering. Here is my attempt:

$${ S_{plate} = \frac{F}{N\times d \times t} }$$

$${ 50ksi = \frac{ 55tons \times\frac{2204.622lb_f}{1ton} }{N \times \frac{5}{16}in \times \frac{7}{16}in} }$$

I get N = 17...

I think what I'm getting wrong is the conversion of tons; I've tried UK Tons, US Tons but nothing. Is there a correct conversion factor?

Comment: If this is for a test in the USA, I imagine it will use the short ton (2000 lb) unless otherwise noted.

Comment: that is one poorly worded exam question. Is that a literal copy or from someone's memory?  What exam is this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The shear force required should depend upon the shear area: 
$$N \pi \biggl(\frac{5}{16}''\biggr) \biggl(\frac{7}{16}''\biggr)$$
 or number times circumference times height, since the side-walls of $N$ cylinders are resisting.

That would drop your answer by almost exactly the right amount. Short tons could take it the rest of the way. Doing the math quickly with short tons gets me $N = 5.122$, which of course we can't have part of a same-sized hole, so we need the floor, or $5$, the desired solution.

With long tons we get $N=5.634$, which has the same floor.

As pointed out by idkfa, I did not consider the safety factor. However, as the question asks about a production process and not an application for the end product, it isn't clear that the safety factor is relevant, in the same way that the SAE designation of the material is (mostly) irrelevant.

Comment: I'm just curious where does the safety factor weigh in here?

Comment: Good point, I don't see it myself. I was in a hurry writing this answer and missed that component. However I am unsure of where it fits in. Although, I am not sure WHY a safety factor is needed, as the question asks about a production process, and not about an application for the product.